# Vuejs : Vue.component not seems to work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, client-side

I am unsure am I doing something wrong but the vuejs component I declared is not working.

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>

</div>

  <ol>
  <!-- Create an instance of the todo-item component -->
  <todo-item></todo-item>
</ol>
```

JavaScript:

```
var a = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})

Vue.component('todo-item', 
{
  template: '<li>This is a todo</li>'
})
```

I am using the JsFiddle, message part does display the data but the todo-item didn't show anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component needs to inside your "#app" div.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
    <ol>
        <!-- Create an instance of the todo-item component -->
        <todo-item></todo-item>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1thsnr8/).

Answer (score 2):

`Vue.component` has to be called **before** `new Vue` in order for the Vue instance to use the component. [From the docs (which aren't all that clear on this, admittedly):](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration)

> These components are globally registered. That means they can be used in the template of any root Vue instance (new Vue) created **after** registration.

```
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  template: '<li>This is a todo</li>'
})

var a = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

That, and your app's code has to all be inside of the `#app` div, as pointed out by CUGreen's answer.

Comment: it make sense.... https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html I follow this link but I can't see that sentence.